# How to improve an already optimized query that takes 18 seconds?

Tags: mysql, optimization

So I have a vps with 512mb ram, and a MySQL table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `value1` char(31) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `value2` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `value3` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `value4` mediumtext collate utf8_unicode_ci,
  `type` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `date` (`ts`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=469692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
  COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

If I execute a query like this, it takes 2~18 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT `id`, `ts`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3` FROM table1 WHERE
`type` = 'something' ORDER BY `id` DESC limit 0,10;
```

EXPLAIN SELECT tells me:

```
  select_type: SIMPLE
         type: ref
possible_keys: type
          key: type
      key_len: 92
          ref: const
         rows: 7291
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
```

I thought the 'using filesort' might be the problem, but it turns out
that's not the case.  If I remove the ORDER BY and the LIMIT, the
query speed is the same (I turn off query cache for the testing with
`SET @@query_cache_type=0;`).

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `id`,`ts`,`value1`,`value2`, `value3` 
       FROM table1 WHERE `type` = 'something'\G

  select_type: SIMPLE
         type: ref
possible_keys: type
          key: type
      key_len: 92
          ref: const
         rows: 7291
        Extra: Using where
```

Don't know if it matters but the rows
approximation is inaccurate:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE `type` = 'something';
```

Returns 22.8k rows.

The query seems already optimized, I don't know how I could further
improve it.  The whole table contains 370k rows, and is about 4.6 GiB
in size.  Could it be possible that because the type is randomly
changing row by row (randomly distributed in the whole table), it
takes 2~18 seconds just to fetch the data from disk?

The funny thing is when I use a type that only has a few hundred rows,
those queries are slow too.  MySQL returns rows at about 100 rows/sec!

```
|-------+------+-----------|
| count | time |   row/sec |
|-------+------+-----------|
| 22802 | 18.7 | 1219.3583 |
|    11 |  0.1 |      110. |
|   491 |  4.8 | 102.29167 |
|   705 |  5.6 | 125.89286 |
|   317 |  2.6 | 121.92308 |
|-------+------+-----------|
```

Why is it so slow?  Can I further optimize the query?  Should I move
the data to smaller tables?

I thought automatic partitioning would be a good idea, to make a new
partition for every type dynamically.  That is not possible, for
many reasons including that the maximum partition number is 1024, and
there can be any types.  I could also try application level
partitioning, creating a new table for every new type.  I wouldn't
want to do that as it introduces great complexity.  I don't know how I
could have a unique id for all rows in all tables.  Also, if I reach
multiple inserts/second, performance would drop significantly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you select only index columns, eg. "select id from..."? Also, does the table fit in ram or will it fetch thousands if rows from disk? What type of disk? The usual answer in this scenario is: make sure your disks are fast and that all tables fit in ram so your disks don't matter :)   (Given the query IS a simple select and indices are properly set up)

Comment: selecting only the index columns is the same speed, 100 rows/sec. since its a vps (512mb ram!) i have no control or info on the disks, and there is not enough ram for a significant part of the database.

Comment: @atlau What happens if *only* `type` is selected for the result set? If covering the result entirely makes it significantly faster, then using a *complete covering index* may help up that specific query.... at the expense of maintenance.

Comment: Where you executing the `select` statement from? Are you executing it directly on the server, or across a network/intranet/VPN/the internet?

Comment: Finding a proper VPS with lots of RAM could be cheaper than the engineer hours spent on solving this problem (and even if you solve it, with 512 RAM you will have another problem in the next month)

Comment: i execute the queries from the mysql command line, logged in with ssh.

Comment: Do you really have a fixed-length 31-character string?  That takes 93 bytes for every row.  Change to ascii to get fixed 31 bytes, or to VARCHAR(31).

Answer (score 4):

You need a multi-column index for that query:

```
KEY `typeid` (`type`, `id`)
```

Unfortunately, as you stated, it is also slow without the ORDER *so* it's slow because the records are scattered around on the disk and it has to do a lot of seeks. Once cached, it should be quite fast (Note: 22.8/370 * 4.6G = 283M, so if you do other activities/queries those record won't be in the memory for long time or might not even fit.).

Do an `iostat 1` to verify the I/O bottleneck. Loads of RAM could solve your problem. An SSD could also solve your problem. But RAM is cheaper ;)

Comment: Why/how would it help? Poster reports that speed is same even when removing `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I already tried multi column index on my development machine, and did not find any speed improvements (didn't try on the server though). Yes, the problem could be because the disk seeks, as i said in my question.

Comment: Cache in 370k records of that size in 512MB...? ;) No sir, not today.

Comment: @pst: You only need the working set in the memory, I don't know the usage patterns for that DB. But yeah, 512M for a database server is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are desperate about optimizing you can try to re-arrange your table. First off you select and order every row from a type and rewrite it to a new table and add the other types to that table one-by-one. I suggest a kind of table defragmentation but I don't have any experience with this.

Comment: This is MyISAM so any DDL will create a copy of the table, and a simple `ALTER TABLE table1 ORDER BY type` should do the same. Of course it doesn't mean that the new table won't be fragmented if your disk doesn't have enough contiguous free space.

Comment: What is the definition of DDL?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to improve a query. In your case, I see that your index must be kind of huge because of the indexed Unicode VARCHAR(30) column responsible for `key_len: 92`. Here's what you can try: replace the big VARCHAR index with something much smaller. Keep the `type` column but remove the index and create a new indexed column `typeidx` which you can create as a INT UNSIGNED (or SMALLINT if possible).

Create a table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE `typetable` (
  `typeidx` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `type` varchar(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`typeidx`),
  UNIQUE KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Which you fill with the existing types

```
INSERT INTO typetable (type) SELECT DISTINCT type FROM table1;
```

Then you have to update `table1.typeidx` with something like

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN typetable tt USING (type)
   SET t1.typeidx = tt.typeidx
```

Now your old query can become something like that

```
SELECT `id`,`ts`,`value1`,`value2`, `value3` 
   FROM table1 WHERE `typeidx` = (SELECT typeidx FROM typetable WHERE type = 'something')
```

Of course you'll also have to maintain `typetable` and insert new values from `type` as they are created.

Comment: And the only point in this would be to reduce the key length from 92?

Comment: Yes. The key length would be 4 for `INT`, 3 for `MEDIUMINT` or 2 for `SMALLINT`. Alternatively, you could look into [the `ENUM` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html) which wouldn't require you to change your `SELECT` query but would require to update the `ENUM` everytime a new value for `type` must be inserted. It's also limited to 65535 possible values.

Comment: Also, if `type` values are exclusively made of ASCII chars you should change its charset to ASCII so that characters are encoded on 1 byte rather than 3+.

Comment: Josh: What intrigue me of your anwser is the query (no joins). Did you have a bad day?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you're talking about, if you have specific questions about a query I'll be happy to clear any misunderstanding. By the way, have you tried this solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I have no better idea than to implement vertical partitioning. I made an identical table without the mediumtext column, copied the whole table without this column, and the 18 sec query takes only 100ms now! The new table is only 55mb.